# Plain While Screen while running application

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm making a Dialer application and I'm following this guide [Simple Dialer Application](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/simple-dialer-application/) The only difference is that I'm using Fragments(with support libraries) rather than Activity approach.
When I try to run the app it compiles fine but displays a plain white screen.
Is the fragments not implemented correctly or I'm somehow getting into an infinite loop?
Please any help is Appreciated
Thanks in Advance!

Here's my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.heroicjokester.android.haid;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


public class DialerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialer);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = new DialerFragment();

        if(fragment == null){
            fragment = new DialerFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
}
}
```

My activity_dialer.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment_dialer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_pno"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/input_pno_hint"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dial_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/dial_button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

DialerFragment.java:

```
 package com.heroicjokester.android.haid;

 import android.Manifest;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Toast;;
 import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

/**
  * Created by Ripcord on 01-Apr-16.
  */
 public class DialerFragment extends Fragment {
 private EditText mPhoneField;
 private Button mDialButton;

//Requesting Permissions using Runtime Permissions.
final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS=0;

private void InitiateCall(){
    int hasCallPermission =          ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
    if (hasCallPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        return;
    }
    InitiateCall();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults ){
   switch (requestCode){
       case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
           if (grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
               //YAY! PERMISSION GRANTED
               InitiateCall();
           }else{
               //GD! PERMISSION DENIED
               Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.permission_denied, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
            break;
       default:
           super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

   }
}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialer,container,false);

    mPhoneField=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.input_pno);
    mDialButton=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.dial_button);

    mDialButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            try{
                if (mPhoneField != null && (mPhoneField.getText().length()==10||mPhoneField.getText().length()==11)){
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + mPhoneField.getText())));
                }
                else if(mPhoneField != null && mPhoneField.getText().length()==0){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),R.string.no_number_toast,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(mPhoneField !=null && mPhoneField.getText().length()<10){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),R.string.wrong_number_toast,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("DialerAppActivity","error: " + e.getMessage(),e);//Runtime error will be logged
            }
        }
    });


    return v;
}

}
```

Finally my log file:

```
 04-01 16:55:56.067 2372-2372/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
 04-01 16:55:56.143 2372-2372/com.heroicjokester.android.haid W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.heroicjokester.android.haid-1/lib/x86
 04-01 16:55:56.173 2372-2385/com.heroicjokester.android.haid D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
 04-01 16:55:56.279 2372-2385/com.heroicjokester.android.haid I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
 04-01 16:55:56.564 2372-2385/com.heroicjokester.android.haid W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
 04-01 16:55:56.564 2372-2385/com.heroicjokester.android.haid W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabfebbe0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
 04-01 16:55:57.263 2372-2372/com.heroicjokester.android.haid I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 04-01 17:01:31.638 2372-2378/com.heroicjokester.android.haid W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.827ms
 04-01 17:06:24.378 2372-2378/com.heroicjokester.android.haid W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.026ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if(fragment == null)` never returns `true`, therefore your fragment transaction is never getting called. I assume you are trying to make sure the fragment doesn't get replaced upon orientation change, in which case you should try to find the fragment first, and if it is not found, create a new one:

```
private static final String FRAGMENT_TAG_DIALER = "fragment:dialer";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialer);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = (DialerFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG_DIALER);

    if(fragment == null){
        fragment = new DialerFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG_DIALER)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! that worked!
Can you please explain me what do these changes mean?

And now the app works fine but I cant dial it, it says permission denial for call service in my log

Comment: @HeroicJokester Basically the method `FragmentTransaction.add(int, fragment, string)` adds a "tag" to the fragment. `findFragmentByTag()` searches the layout (the one set with `setContentView()`) for a fragment with the the specified *tag*. If the fragment with that *tag* is not found, it returns `null`. So now you can check if the fragment is null, before creating a new one.

Comment: @HeroicJokester As for your permission issue, what is your `targetSdkVersion`? If it is set to 23 or higher, you need to follow the new [permissions model](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), and request permissions at runtime.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful and I edited my code to ask permission on runtime but the app doesn't show me that dialog box where you permit the app, but if I go in Settings/Applications and manually enable the permission it works fine.
Please look at my class DialerFragment I updated it with the new code and tell me what im doing wrong.

Comment: @HeroicJokester Your `InitiateCall()` method looks like it only asks for permission, it never makes a call. It actually looks like you are creating an infinite recursion condition. You should have one method (say, `initCall()`) that checks for permission, then another method (`makeCall()`), that is called if the permission is granted. If you are still having trouble with it, I suggest asking another question. If you post a link to it here I will take a look.

Comment: Good advice, Asked another question here's the link:
[How to properly ask for permissions on Runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36410339/how-to-properly-ask-for-permissions-on-run-time).